# elixir.queueTask is undefined

Tags: gulp, laravel-elixir

I am fairly new to Laravel 5.2 and Elixir/gulp but I have an issue with queueTask being undefined when I run gulp from the command line.

What I want to do is to extend elixir to delete some files (according to all the documentation I can find, that's what I need to do), so I have this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var elixir = require("laravel-elixir");
var del = require('del');

elixir.extend("remove", function(path) {
        gulp.task("removeFiles", function() {
            return del(path);
        });
        return this.queueTask("removeFiles");
    });
```

and then in my mix I have:

```
    .remove([
        "path/to/file1/filename1",
        "path/to/file2/filename2"
    ])
```

When I run gulp in the command line, I get:

```
return this.queueTask("removeFiles");
            ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

can anyone throw some light on what I am doing wrong please?

Answer (score 4):

API has changed again since Elixir v3.0.0. So for v4.0.0 you must do this:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
var del = require('del');

var Task = elixir.Task;

elixir.extend('remove', function (path) {
    new Task('remove', function () {
        return del(path);
    });
});
```

And then you can call it within your pipeline like this:

```
mix.remove([
    "path/to/file1/filename1",
    "path/to/file2/filename2"
]);
```

The difference seems to be calling `elixir.extend` as opposed to `elixir.Task.extend`. And then returning a `new elixir.Task`.

Comment: thank you for var Task = elixir.Task; this saved my day:) btw we can new elixir.Task ('taskname',function(){........}); too.

Answer (score 0):

API was changed in [Elixir v3.0.0.](https://github.com/laravel/elixir/releases)

You no longer need to call `Gulp.task()`. Elixir will handle that, instead you have to create a new Task.

```
var Elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
var del = require('del');

Elixir.Task.extend('remove', function (path) {
    new Task('remove', function () {
        return del(path);
    });
});
```